# Share viewModel between a composable and an activity

Tags: android, dependency-injection, android-jetpack-compose, viewmodel, dagger-hilt

i can inject the same viewmodel in a composable that belongs to ActivityA and an ActivityB but couldn't have the same instance, how can i provide the same instance of the viewmodel using Dagger Hilt ? is there any way out of the box ?

Answer (score 0):

Should be fairly straightforward:

in your hilt module create a function that's able to provide your view model instance (make sure your viewModel is marked as `@HiltViewModel` and has `@inject constructor()`, even if empty)

```kotlin
@Provides
@Singleton
fun providesXViewModel(/* if your vm requires parameters provided by hilt, place them here, e.g.: dao: Dao*/): XViewModel = XViewModel(/* and then here, e.g.: dao*/)
```

and that should (*I think*) allow you to inject the viewModel into your activities and then use them in your composables (I would suggest field injection)

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ExampleActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

  @Inject lateinit var vm: XViewModel
  ...
}
```

Comment: Btw, consider passing lambdas to composables, instead of the entire VM